# Numbers stored with decimal point but always displayed with decimal comma regardless locale settings

Tags: angular, ionic4

I'm working on an app that displays weights (in kg) with one decimal digit, e.g., 92.5 kg. I store the numbers with a decimal point in IndexedDB but they're always displayed in the Ionic 4 page as 92,5 regardless of what DecimalPipe I used, e.g., 'en-US' should have decimal points but when I set it like this

```
{{ this.value | number:'1.1-1':'en'}}
```

the value is still displayed with a decimal comma.

I checked my Chrome settings but it is also set to the english language. I'm in the Netherlands myself where we have decimal comma's and use points to separate multiples of 1000.

I'm using Ionic 4 (out of the box) on a Mac

Any help would be appreciated!

Ralph

Comment: Maybe you could try something like this: $locale.NUMBER_FORMATS.GROUP_SEP = ',';

Comment: and it looks like DECIMAL_SEP is the property name for the decimal separator.

Comment: Ok, and where would I add that $locale statement?

Comment: Assuming you want it everywhere in your app maybe somewhere near the root of your app.  Maybe try it just in the component/controller where you're display the {{ this.value....}} above first

Comment: Thnx, I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: I cannot get it to work. There are quite a few examples of how you can set the locale  in Ionic 4 (e.g., registerLocaleData) but none of these seem to have any effect.

Comment: Forunately, the app accepts float-point numbers both with points or comma's so the user can choose